# How can I do visual development in Eclipse using JSF's Trinidad UI library?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, trinidad

I want to be able to do visual development in Eclipse for the Trinidad JSF library (just like you can now do with Oracle ADF Faces in Eclipse).

Is it possible to do visual development in Eclipse with Trinidad? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Oracle Enterprise for Eclipse - it should give you some level of visual development with Trinidad.
For a sample:
http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/2011/02/adf_faces_now_in_eclipse.html
free download from OTN

Comment: Shay -- can you please make an edit to your answer. I accidentally hit the down arrow instead of the plus arrow. If you make an edit, I can switch to a +1.

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to only work with ADF Faces and not Trinidad components.